# Problem mapping an array received from nodejs in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to use an array returned from Node in a React code.

Here's the Node's router code:

```
router.get('/prodlist', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Product.find({}).exec((err, result) => {
      res.status(200).send({ express: result })
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400).send(e)
  }
})
```

The React's component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    var curURL = window.location.href
    var calledRoute = curURL.substr(8).substr(curURL.substr(8).indexOf("/"))
    callBackendAPI(calledRoute)
      .then(res => setDatas(prevData => res.express))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, [])

  async function callBackendAPI(routePath) {
    const response = await fetch(routePath);
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) {
      throw Error(body.message)
    }
    console.log(body.express)
    return body;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {{datas}}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And the array content (seen from Chrome's developer tools):

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  0:
    prodDesc: "Prod1"
    prodID: "1"
    prodImage: "prod1.jpg"
    prodPrice: 350
    prodRebate: 100
    prodReviews: []
    prodStock: 31
    prodThumb: "prod1.jpg"
    __v: 0
    _id: "5eb04a6439eec26af4981541"
    __proto__: Object
  1: {prodID: "2", prodDesc: "Prod2", prodThumb: "prod2.jpg", prodImage: "prod2.jpg", prodPrice: 1500.79, …}
  2: {prodID: "3", prodDesc: "Prod3", prodThumb: "prod3.jpg", prodImage: "prod3.jpg", prodPrice: 280.79, …}
  length: 3
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

When I execute this code I get the error: Objects are not valid as a React child

So I tried to map data's content with a line like this:

```
{datas.map((item) => <p>{item}</p>)}
```

Executing this code with a map I get the error : Cannot read property 'map' of null.

Although datas contains an array, it seems React sees it as null.

Anybody understands this issue?

EDIT: I didn't realized that this question is about two different issues. Norbitrial's answer fixed the problem about synchronicity but I still get the error "Objects are not valid as a React child [...] use an array instead".

EDIT2: Solved the issue by forwarding the mapping to a REACT component with the following line:

```
{datas && datas.map(item => <ShopCart key={item.prodID} item={item} />)}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Not related to your problem at hand, but you are doing your async function on the server incorrectly. It will still work, but your `await` isn't going to do anything since it's a function that has a callback function rather than one that returns a Promise. You can use `require('utils').promisify` to convert the function to a Promise-returning one: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your backend API returns the result asynchronously so it might take few seconds while your state value is `null`.

The solution can be checking for `null` value first then using the `.map()` on your state called `datas` with `&&` in your code.

Try as the following:

```
{datas && datas.map((item) => <p>{item}</p>)}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The code runs before `datas` is populated from your api, you need to first check to make sure it is populated like this.

```
{datas && datas.length && datas.map((item) => <p>{item}</p>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your component gets mounted before you receive the data.

What I would do(and most people) is to create a loading component that will show a spinner or something like that when the array is empty and after it gets filled it should render the component with the data.

But a quick solution to this is to do a conditional render

```js
{datas.length && datas.map((item) => <p>{item}</p>)}
```